# How to select name and count how many time name is repeated in one query with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

Im trying to make report for invoice and im looking to pull profit out name than count how many times are repeated and show price for unit and total the final result should look something like this

```
 Name      Quantity       Unit Price      Total

 Rent      2                $ 120         $ 240

 Ремонт    1                $ 350         $ 350
```

Current query

```
SELECT p.profitout_price,  p.description, pd.name
    FROM profit_out p
    LEFT JOIN profit_description pd ON (p.profitout_id = pd.id)
```

Result

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [profitout_price] => 150
        [description] => Дюзи
        [name] => Ремонт
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [profitout_price] => 120
        [description] => 
        [name] => Rent
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [profitout_price] => 120
        [description] => 
        [name] => Rent
    )

)
```

what i tried to do it add COUNT to pd.name like this

```
SELECT p.profitout_price,  p.description, pd.name, COUNT(pd.name) AS count
```

but result is incorect and become like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [profitout_price] => 120
        [count] => 3
        [description] => 
        [name] => Rent
    )

)
```

How to get the correct result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution, using a `GROUP BY` with `MIN` and `SUM`:

```
SELECT
  pd.name AS `Name`,
  COUNT(pd.id) AS `Quantity`,
  MIN(p.profitout_price) AS `Unit Price`,
  SUM(p.profitout_price) AS `Total`
FROM profit_out p LEFT JOIN profit_description pd ON p.profitout_id = pd.id
GROUP BY pd.name
```

You have to `GROUP BY` profit name. You can use `COUNT` to get the quantity and `SUM` to get the total.

**Note:** If you don't need the description of the profit you can remove the `LEFT JOIN`.